# Node.js - spawn gzip process

Tags: javascript, process, node.js, spawn

I'm trying to gzip some data using Node.js...

Specifically, I have data in 'buf' and I want to write a gzipped form of this to 'stream'.

Here is my code:

```
c1.on('data',function(buf){
                var gzip = spawn('gzip', ['-' + (compressionRate-0),'-c', '-']);

                gzip.stdin.write(buf);
                gzip.stdout.on('data',function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        stream.write(data,'binary');
                });
});
```

The trouble is, it simply won't work! I'm not sure of the exact syntax for spawning processes and piping data to them.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Edit: here is the original working code where I got the idea from. The project is at: https://github.com/indutny/node.gzip

Can anyone work out how to do this spawning in node.js cos I'm totally stuck!

---

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

module.exports = function (data) {
    var rate = 8,
        enc = 'utf8',
        isBuffer = Buffer.isBuffer(data),
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        callback;

    if (!isBuffer && typeof args[0] === 'string') {
        enc = args.shift();
    }
    if (typeof args[0] === 'number') {
        rate = args.shift() - 0;
    }
    callback = args[0];

    var gzip = spawn('gzip', ['-' + (rate - 0), '-c', '-']);

    var promise = new
    process.EventEmitter,
        output = [],
        output_len = 0;

    // No need to use buffer if no
    callback was provided
    if (callback) {
        gzip.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            output.push(data);
            output_len += data.length;
        });

        gzip.on('exit', function (code) {
            var buf = new Buffer(output_len);

            for (var a = 0, p = 0; p < output_len; p += output[a++].length) {
                output[a].copy(buf, p, 0);
            }
            callback(code, buf);
        });
    }
    // Promise events  
    gzip.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        promise.emit('data', data);
    });
    gzip.on('exit', function (code) {
        promise.emit('end');
    });

    if (isBuffer) {
        gzip.stdin.encoding = 'binary';
        gzip.stdin.end(data.length ? data : '');
    } else {
        gzip.stdin.end(data ? data.toString() : '', enc);
    }

    // Return EventEmitter, so node.gzip can be used for streaming 
    // (thx @indexzero for that tip) 
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: You could try two things : set the stdout.on('data' BEFORE writing to the stdin, in case anything comes up and also, listen on the stderr in case there is an error message that you aren't catching.

Comment: Yes, that's something I'm doing right now. Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to call the 'end' method on gzip.stdin? I.e.:

```
gzip.stdin.write(buf);
gzip.stdout.on('data',function(data){
        console.log(data);
        stream.write(data,'binary');
});
gzip.stdin.end();
```

Comment: That's certainly something I didn't do. When I call stdin.end() I get some data moving around! Trouble is, I now have another error that appears: "Error: Offset is out of bounds" P.s. I've edited my OP to provide more information. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply use the gzip node library that you are "inspired from" instead of copying the code?

```
var gzip = require('gzip');
c1.on('data' function(buf){
    gzip(buf, function(err, data){
        stream.write(data, 'binary');
    }
}
```

Should work using the library. To install it simply type `npm install gzip` in your terminal.

Comment: I know. But it's (IMO) buggy - I keep getting buffer errors. I'm trying to rebuild it from the ground up from spawn command, so I can figure out what's going wrong. Also, node.gzip doesn't have unzip. I've created an unzip module (based on indunty's code) for node which works fine, but I'm still getting some buffer errors.